# Generic trait implementation errors

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

This trait declaration and definition one works correctly without any problem:

```
trait FTrait<T>: Fn(T, T) -> T {}
impl<T, F> FTrait<T> for F where F: Fn(T, T) -> T, {}
...
fn hof(f: impl FTrait<u32>) -> impl FTrait<u32> { //fourth with a generic trait in use with concrete types
    move |a, b| {
        let r = f(a, b);
        r
    }
}
```

But this trait declaration gives multiple errors:

```
    trait FTraitBorrowed<'a, T>: Fn(&'a T, &'a T) -> &'a T {}
    impl<'a, T, F> FTraitBorrowed<'a, T: 'a, F> for F where F: Fn(&'a T, &T) -> &'a T, {}

....
fn hof_borrowed(f: impl FTraitBorrowed<i32>) -> impl FTraitBorrowed<i32 > {
    move |a, b| {
        let r = f(a, b);
        r
    }
```

The errors are listed here:

```
Errors:
error: associated type bindings must be declared after generic parameters
  --> src\main.rs:44:31
   |
44 | impl<'a, T, F> FTraitBorrowed<'a, T: 'a, F> for F where F: Fn(&'a T, &T) -> &'a T, {}
   |                               ^^^^-----^^^
   |                                   |
   |                                   this associated type binding should be moved after the generic parameters

error[E0658]: associated type bounds are unstable
  --> src\main.rs:44:35
   |
44 | impl<'a, T, F> FTraitBorrowed<'a, T: 'a, F> for F where F: Fn(&'a T, &T) -> &'a T, {}
   |                                   ^^^^^
   |
   = note: for more information, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52662

error[E0229]: associated type bindings are not allowed here
  --> src\main.rs:44:35
   |
44 | impl<'a, T, F> FTraitBorrowed<'a, T: 'a, F> for F where F: Fn(&'a T, &T) -> &'a T, {}
   |                                   ^^^^^ associated type not allowed here

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0229, E0658.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0229`.
```

Could not clearly understand what are wrong from the hints.

For the first error goes away, if I interchange the positions of F and T like this in the implementation:

```
impl<'a, T, F> FTraitBorrowed<'a, F, T: 'a, > ...
```

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that causes the errors is that type bounds aren't allowed there:

```rust
// correct
impl<'a, T: 'a, F> FTraitBorrowed<'a, T, F> ...

// wrong
impl<'a, T, F> FTraitBorrowed<'a, T: 'a, F> ...
```

Because of this, Rust thought that you're using the unstable feature [associated type bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52662), which caused the confusing error messages.

There were also some other issues, which I managed to fix ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cd7267505e117ec108ab5b68f256d2f1)):

```rust
trait FTraitBorrowed<'a, T: 'a>: Fn(&'a T, &'a T) -> &'a T {}

impl<'a, T: 'a, F> FTraitBorrowed<'a, T> for F where F: Fn(&'a T, &'a T) -> &'a T {}

fn hof_borrowed<'a, F>(f: impl FTraitBorrowed<'a, i32>) -> impl FTraitBorrowed<'a, i32> {
    move |a, b| f(a, b)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got confused by the syntaxes... Also thanks for pointing out the other fixes. Best

Comment: How can I pass a closure/function to hof_borrowed()? Could you please show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: For simplicity, I changed the return value to T, instead of &T in the FTraitBorrowed. And then tried calling hof_borrowed(|&x, &y| x + y ), which gives error "error[E0282]: type annotations needed -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `F` declared on the function `hof_borrowed`. If I try to add a turbofish after the function, like hof_borrowed::<i32>(|&x, &y| x + y ), it gives error, error[E0632]: cannot provide explicit generic arguments when `impl Trait` is used in argument position. Thanks

Comment: @Prana please add a playground link, so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Could someone please help on this? Thanks.

Comment: I could make it work. The syntax of the function has to change. fn hof_borrowed<'a, F: FTraitBorrowed<'a, i32>>(f: F) -> impl FTraitBorrowed<'a, i32> {
    move |a, b| f(a, b)
}. Here's the playground link... https://play.rust-lang.org/